# Back button not working after crash

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I have an app with two activities.
When the app starts it shows a constant notification which is turned off only when pressing back twice from the main activity.

While running the app if a crash happens on the main activity, the notification stays, when trying to return to the app it returns to the Second activity, and the back button only exits the app (Leaving the notification on).

That way the main activity is not accessible and shutting down the app by pressing back twice is not an option.

In that case the only option left is to forcibly shutdown the app through the phone's app manager.

Any Idea on how to keep the previous activity and be able to return to it?

Comment: have you overriden the onBackPressed method? post some code

Comment: So your app crashes and instead of fixing it you want to fix the effects that crash has on your app?

Comment: Try to resolve the crash instead of fixing the crash effects.

Comment: Application crash, that is a fact. Every time I discover a bug I fix it. Despite that fact, my app WILL have more bugs (I believe no one is perfect, let alone me). Taking that into consideration, I want my app to crush while leaving the least amount of  side effects on the system or the user. Any way @Wukash thank you for the cynicism, that was very helpful.

Comment: @me1982 but instead you could have typed what the current problem is that is causing the crash

Comment: @Shreyans Happens whether or not I override onBackPressed

Comment: "While running the app if a crash happens on the main activity, the notification stays, when trying to return to the app it returns to the Second activity" . Why does your app returns to Second activity after crash instead of MAIN activity?

Comment: @me1982 well you can override it and the explicitly define what happens when back is pressed. have you tried that?

Comment: @Wukash That is a great question to which I do not know the answer.

Comment: @Shreyans I have tried starting a new intent of the main activity when back is pressed from the second activity, but all it does is making duplicate activities and you need to exit the app several time before it actually closes (According to the amount of times you pressed back).

Comment: In your manifest, inside activity tag, add android:launchMode="singleTop" to avoid duplicating activities. When you start activity with the intent and activity already exists it will just go to that activity without duplicating

Comment: @me1982 yes you could do what Wukash has said and you could also simply use finish() to pop your current activity from backstack. read about tasks and backstack first

Comment: @Wukash Great answer - seems to work great. In general it seems that I would like to use singleTop for most of my activities. Is their a reason why I should not use it? Isn't it better in terms of repetitive load speed and resource usage?

Comment: @me1982 Well most of the time you want just one copy of each activity, so unless you need many of them for a specific reason, I don't think there is a reason not to use singleTop launch mode.